# Insert Command phpMyAdmin Error when logged in through cPanel

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I'm logging into phpMyAdmin through cPanel and when inserting

```
INSERT INTO `ci`.`categories` (
`cat_id` ,
`cat_name` ,
`cat_shortdesc` ,
`cat_longdesc` ,
`cat_parentid`
 )
 VALUES
 ('1', 'Uncategorized', 'Should be Categorized soon...', 'All the stuff that did not fit     in the main categories.', '0'), 
 ('2', 'Action/Adventure', 'Shoot to kill.', 'Excitement is the bane of our existence. Why not help fulfil that craving?', '0'),
 ('3', 'RPG', 'Play as someone you actually like.', 'RPGs are unique that they existed before computers. Help. I cannot think of descriptions.', '0'), 
 ('4', 'Simulation', 'SIMULATE EVERYTHING', 'Probably from Germany. All sims are from Germany... right?', '0');
```

I'm getting the error

1142 - INSERT command denied to user 'scottrot'@'localhost' for table 'categories'

I've tried to use grant user but I also get access denied for that. Is it because I'm logging into phpMyAdmin through cPanel credentials? I can't figure out how to login to other SQL accounts.

Answer (score 0):

- You need the root user for the mysql database or a user with privileges to grant you insert privileges.

Comment: I don't enter any username and passwords to gain access to SQL or phpmyadmin. It takes credentials off of the login to cpanel.

Comment: Have you assigned the user to the database?

Comment: I've added them in MySQLDataBases but either I can't figure out how to login to phpmyadmin with the accounts.

Comment: please try other queries (SELECT, UPDATE) to see if they work

Comment: I had no problems with CREATE... does that help? Also I ran SELECT 1 + 1 just to check and that worked as well.